# BigQuery: How to group similar records of an array together into comma separated field?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I have a text field that is a comma separated file.  The records look like this

```
SKU                  Info
123                Common:  tshirt
345                common:  jeans, color: green
567                common:  tshirt, common: jeans, color: blue
```

I'm trying to get these into arrays but combining where the first word is the same.  IE: for record 3 above (567) the array field would be

```
  common:  tshirt, jeans
  color: blue
```

my current query:

```
 select   array(select trim(val) from unnest(split(trim(infos, ''))) val) as testing
```

returns

```
567    common: jeans
567    common: tshirt
567    color:  blue
```

Any insight or help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select sku, array(
    select any_value(split(trim(val), ':')[offset(0)]) || ': ' ||
      string_agg(split(trim(val), ':')[offset(1)], ', ') 
    from unnest(split(trim(info, ''))) val
    group by split(trim(val), ':')[offset(0)]
  ) as testing
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  Although I modified it slightly, had to get rid of nulls and do a "Safe_offset"

{  , array(
    (select any_value(split(trim(val), ':')[safe_offset(0)]) || ': ' ||
        string_agg(split(trim(val), ':')[safe_offset(1)], ', ') 
     from unnest(split(trim(infos, ''))) val
     WHERE regexp_extract(val, r'^(.*?)\:') IS NOT NULL
     group by split(trim(val), ':')[safe_offset(0)])
  ) as infosArray}